# Diagonal elements of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If in matrix,all non-diagonal elements are zero but some of the diagonal elements are also zero then can we call it a diagonal matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By definition a diagonal matrix is a matrix where every element outside the diagonal is $0$. So whenever that is satisfied, independent of the elements on the diagonal, we can call the matrix a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's a perfectly fine diagonal matrix. (You will see those types of matrices when you try and diagonalize a non-invertible matrix.)

The stuff below doesnt answer your question but offers some insight into what a matrix like this would do:

Furthermore, this corresponds to an intuition of what a diagonal matrix does. Note that if you have all nonzero entries along the diagonal, then you have an invertible matrix, and it acts like an invertible matrix. If you have a zero then it's non invertible.

The way diagonal matrices act on vectors as a transform is that each coordinate of the vector is "scaled" by the corresponding diagonal entries. What happens if you let one entry go to zero? No matter what, the result of multiplying that matrix onto a vector will always result in a vector with one coordinate zero, so this type of diagonal matrix maps vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a subspace of a lower dimension. In fact, that's precisely what non-invertible matrices do, so everything works.